# Do you have any download hit counter per user Module in joomla?

Tags: php, javascript, performance, joomla

In my project one download button is there . if user download button click then i will show count of download .

is it possiable have any module for download hit counter ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. A programming question would be something like, "How would I go about implementing a hit counter in PHP using Joomla?"

Answer (score 1):

These 2 modules support download counters but require the content to be hosted in a specific way:

- http://www.rocketwerx.com/products/rokdownloads/overview
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-&-documentation/downloads/3115/details